# Identifying the wooden puzzle-box featured in Tomb Raider

Tags: puzzle-identification, mechanical-puzzles

In the film *Tomb Raider* (2018) there is a wooden puzzle-box with rotating sections. Once the correct sequence of moves is performed, a drawer pops out. See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ndhidEmUbI&t=18):

[image]

Upon seeing it she says:

> Karakuri. Japanese puzzle.

Is this rotating design based on a real puzzle? Possibly by the [Karakuri group](https://karakuri.gr.jp/en/)?

---

**Note:** several props were used for filming, all non-functional.

**Note:** as a promo for the film, the studio gave-away similar puzzles:

- https://twitter.com/jade_sura/status/966659174351466496
- https://twitter.com/strawburry17/status/968280241213861888
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=izdeOVzgyHM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you also posted this question [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88107/does-the-wooden-puzzle-from-tomb-raider-really-exist)  and I would agree with the accepted answer there that it looks to be a Codex or Cryptex. The actual prop seems to be just that.

The word "karakuri" generally refers to (I think) [Karakuri puppets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karakuri_puppet) but it has come to mean "mechanisms" or "trick" in Japanese and "is used to describe any device that evokes a sense of awe through concealment of its inner workings". So we can see why they chose that name for the device in the movie.

Interestingly, I stumbled across a video in which someone tries to recreate the puzzle at home. It looks different but is very similar in spirit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y4DE-elBJtg